# Tkinter, I want to change the text of a label, after generating it with a loop

Tags: python, tkinter

So I know the problem is in the, "firstLabelList[2]['text'] = "Yay it worked!" line, but I don't know how to fix it.

from tkinter import *

class LabelLoop():

```
def __init__(self):
    #create the window 
    window =Tk()
    window.title("Tic Tack Toe! Yay Lets do it!")
    window.geometry("350x450")
    #window.columnconfigure((1, 2, 3,), weight=1)
    #window.rowconfigure((1, 2, 3, 4), weight=1)

 

    x=0
    y=0

    firstLabelList= [0]*3

    #ok, so i have a proof of concept, I can create labels using a loop. 
    #The next thing I want to do is prove that I can add logic to the labels, so I want to make a button
    #that changes the third one. 

    for i in range (3):
        firstLabelList[i]=Label(window, text=f"label {i}").grid(row=x, column=y) 
        x+=1

    def on_click():
        firstLabelList[2]['text'] = "Yay it worked!"
        


    changeBttn = Button(window, text="change", command=on_click).grid(row=5, column=0)

    #Here is the problem, how do you fix this? 



    window.mainloop()
```

LabelLoop()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're problem is that your are doing `.grid()` directly. First, create the Label if `firstLabelList`, then access it again and grid it. The `.grid()` does not return the object, so you will get None as the return result.

So, the code in the loop should change to:

```py
for i in range (3):
        firstLabelList[i]=Label(window, text=f"label {i}")
        firstLabelList[i].grid(row=x, column=y) 
        x+=1
```